# Import/export issue

Tags: alfresco

I have a scenario in which I have to export entire information from the Alfresco and import that into another alfresco...

To not find any difference in users, sites, dashlets, rules, aspects and other information. It should work without any difference as like the previous one after import.

I used the plugin share-import-export-0.1-JAR-alfresco-3.4 for import and export in the Alfreso share itself. But my export option in share is not working consistently, sometimes it is successfully exported and some times showing error.

After export if I get the .acp file successfully... I am getting error msg while importing the entire content in share and the error msg also not so descriptive. Err Msg:"Unexpected error occured during content extraction".

Comment: is [backup and restore](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Backup_and_Restore) a viable option for you? In any case, it would be helpful if you can provide the server error logs and / or stack traces.

Comment: I agree that if what you want is an identical system, backup and restore is the way to go. I'm not sure an ACP export will get the users. Also, if you have made any extensions to the content model or other customizations to the alfresco or share wars, don't forget to move those over.

Comment: It does not showing any log error. 
I want the import for sites and end users in different Alfresco application should be get reflected in my  Alfresco application(Both alfresco are two different individual application). I mean the end users from the different Alfresco application should able to log into my alfresco application and works with their sites where the end users are the member of that particular sites and also able to access their same site wiki, blog post,their dashlets in my dashboard and so on without any difference.

Comment: Is there any limit for .acp file size?- kap

Comment: @skuro your link is broken: did you mean this https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.0/admin/migration/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an ACP for your needs. An ACP includes the content and permissions, but not the definitions of the users/groups of those permissions. An ACP also won't include the site definition - there's more to a site than just the content that makes it up.

If you need to export a site, including its contents and its users, then your best bet is to use the new functionality that was introduced into Alfresco 3.5 (Team) to support the sample site. There's a webscript that handles the export, and a bootstrap importer that'll load it into a new system for you. I find it works pretty well for this sort of thing, but then I'm possibly biased as I wrote most of it ;-)

The webscript for the export is `org.alfresco.repository.site.site-export.get`, which lives at `/alfresco/services/api/sites/{shortname}/export` - drop the site name into the URL and fetch (as an admin) to receive the zip with all the parts of the site in it.

To see the loading, take a look at `patch-services-context.xml` and search for `patch.siteLoadPatch.swsdp`. The class that loads is `org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.impl.SiteLoadPatch` and it takes the users, people, groups, content and site name as parameters. (You'll get all of these things in the zip file from the export)

If you need to do multiple sites + users + groups + contents, then you should look at something like import/export, replication/transfer, or rolling something custom yourself (probably based on CMIS).

Comment: (my requirement) I want the import for sites and end users in different Alfresco application should be get reflected in my Alfresco application(Both alfresco are two different individual application). I mean the end users from the different Alfresco application should able to log into my alfresco application and works with their sites where the end users are the member of that particular sites and also able to access their same site wiki, blog post,their dashlets in my dashboard and so on without any difference.Will your webscript works in a way i am expecting?

Comment: I think it should work, yes. Give it a try! It won't keep the two copies in sync though...

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. I have 2 private sites and some documents from one site have associations to some documents in the other site (<view:associations>...</view:associations>). If I use the webscript to export each site one at a time, the cross-associations are lost. Is there a way to export/import both sites at once ?

Comment: IIRC, you'd need to start the export from a point that contained both the sites (i.e. the sites root), and filter to just get the ones of interest